# Pycharmでデバッグして修正を行い、修正箇所から実行することはできますか？

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

以前はJuypter NotebookやGoogle colabを使ってPythonのプログラム作成を行っていましたが、Pycharmでの開発も勉強中です。
Jupyter NotebookやGoogle colabでは、ひとつのコード単位(セル？単位)で実行してエラーが出たら修正を行い再度実行していました。Pycharmでは、デバッグ機能で特定の箇所まで、およびそれ以降の1行づつのデバッグは行なえますが、例えば途中のコードに誤りがあり修正後再度デバッグを実行すると、コードの最初から実行されてしまいます。このようなデバッグして修正して修正箇所だけ再度実行して確認をすることはPycharmではできないのでしょうか。
私がPycharmを理解していないからなのだと思うのですが、皆様がどのように効率的にこのような作業をPycharmで行っているのかご教授いただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 使ったことはないけど, PyCharm **Pro** の Jupyter サポートというのがあるようです。ノートブック UI で Jupyterぽく使える模様 https://www.jetbrains.com/ja-jp/pycharm/whatsnew/2021-3/

Comment: PyCharm自身に機能は無さそうです。[中断されたプログラムを調べる](https://pleiades.io/help/pycharm/examining-suspended-program.html), [パート 1. Python コードのデバッグ](https://pleiades.io/help/pycharm/part-1-debugging-python-code.html), しかしこの記事 [Is there "Edit and Continue" in PyCharm? Reload code into running program like in Eclipse / PyDev?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23333815/9014308) の最後に改善出来そうなプラグインの情報があるので調べてみては？ [Reloadium](https://reloadium.io/documentation/pycharm-plugin), [Hot Reloading aka Edit and Continue for PyCharm](https://www.reddit.com/r/pycharm/comments/tmaxj7/hot_reloading_aka_edit_and_continue_for_pycharm/)

Comment: PyCharm Pro(https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/jupyter-notebook-support.html )やDataSpell (https://www.jetbrains.com/dataspell/ )では Jupyter notebooksが利用可能です。が、これらは有料アプリケーションです。

Comment: Community Editionでもこんなプラグインが使えるかもしれません。[PyCharm cell mode](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7858-pycharm-cell-mode), [How to add and configure code cells in PyCharm Community Edition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_MSyewFfNpc)